# Django selecting a record if its Many-to-Many relation contains data

Tags: django, django-orm

I have these 2 tables

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Collaborator")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Collaborator(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="jobs")
    role = models.CharField()
```

For a user, I want to select all those `Jobs` where either `created_by=user` or the user is in collaborators.

The following query does not produce correct results

```
Job.objects.filter(Q(created_by=user) | Q(collaborators=user))
```

Upon looking at the raw query generated by above code I have found out that this is because the query produced by django ORM creates a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between `Job` and `Collaborator`, so if there are multiple Collaborators for the same Job then it returns multiple rows of the same job.

What I have come up with is the following query

```
Job.objects.filter(Q(created_by=user) | Q(pk__in=user.jobs.all().values("job_id")))
```

My question is, is there a better query than the above that I can use?

P.S. I am using django 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to remove duplicates from the QuerySet, which seems to be the simplest solution:

```
jobs = Job.objects.filter(Q(created_by=user) | Q(collaborators=user)).distinct()
```

But, its also possible to [`group_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-order-by) the results, for instance:

```
jobs = (
    Job.objects.filter(Q(collaborators=user) | Q(created_by=user))
    .annotate(times_repeated=Count('id'))
    .order_by()
)
```

Both options looks better than having a nested query.